# How to programmatically create a custom token in a module

Tags: tokens

How would you go about programmatically creating a token? I wish to add some custom tokens for my module.

Comment: Additional documentation has been updated (Oct 31,2014) and can be found at https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/token

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Drupal 6, you use [`hook_token_values()`](http://api.lullabot.com/hook_token_values).

This hook will allow you to create tokens. You can create them in the global scope or you can use an object like a node, or a user to seed the values.

You should also use [`hook_token_list()`](http://api.lullabot.com/hook_token_list) to explain what your tokens are.

The [token.api](http://api.lullabot.com/file/contrib/token/API.txt/6/source) documentation is quite clear.

```
function my_user_token_values($type, $object = NULL, $options = array()) {
  if ($type == 'user') {
    $user = $object;
    $tokens['name']      = $user->name;
    $tokens['mail']      = $user->mail;
    return $tokens;
  }
}
```

I won't X post the whole thing but that should give you a high level idea.

Answer (score 21):

In Drupal 7 the code for handling tokens is part of the Drupal core module.

The hooks the token modules need to implement are:

- [hook_token_info()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_token_info/7) is the hook that provides information about the tokens implemented by a module.
- [hook_tokens()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_tokens/7) is the hook that needs to be implemented to provide the actual values that replace the tokens.

Other modules can alter the token implementation provided from a module using [hook_token_info_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_token_info_alter/7) and [hook_tokens_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_tokens_alter/7).

Differently from the Token module, the code in Drupal core allows to create the content of a token only when strictly necessary.
In Drupal 6, the Token module would ask to the modules implementing tokens all the values for their token using `hook_token_values()`; this means that a module can compute the value for a token which is then not required for the tokens being replaced. In Drupal 7, the implementation of `hook_tokens()` receives `$tokens`, an array of tokens to be replaced, as argument; the module is then able to compute the value of a token, knowing it will be used.

The function that in Drupal 7 is used to replace the tokens with their value is [token_replace()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--token.inc/function/token_replace/7), which is the only function used to replace the tokens with their values.

Other difference between the Token module for Drupal 6 and the code in Drupal 7 are:

- In Drupal 7, [node:author] returns the name of the author; [node:author:mail] returns the email address associated with the author of a node, and [node:author:url] returns the URL of the user profile for the node author. In other words, it is possible to use [node:author:xyz], where "xyz" is one of the tokens returned for a user object.
- In Drupal 7, there are not raw tokens; the implementation of `hook_tokens()` get a parameter that tells to the hook when the content of the token needs to be sanitized; when the token value doesn't need to be sanitized, the content is not passed to the functions `check_plain()` or `filter_xss()`.
- In Drupal 7, there isn't any function that show the list of the available tokens. If a module needs to show the list of available tokens, it must build the list of the tokens itself and show it in the description of a form field; alternatively, it can use the theme function still available in the Token module.

Answer (score 11):

I wanted to add a new token to the *Site information* section of tokens, called *City name*. This is how I did it in Drupal 7.

```
 /**
 * Implements hook_token_info().
 */
function my_module_token_info() {

  // Add tokens.
  $site['city_name'] = array(
    'name' => t('Token Name'),
    'description' => t('Token Description'),
  );

  return array(
    'tokens' => array(
      'site' => $site,
    ),
  );
}

/**
 * Implements hook_tokens().
 */
function my_module_tokens($type, $tokens, array $data = array(), array $options = array()) {
  $replacements = array();

 if ($type == 'site') {
    foreach ($tokens as $name => $original) {
      switch ($name) {
        case 'city_name':
          $city_name = variable_get('city_name');
          $replacements[$original] = $options['sanitize'] ? check_plain($city_name) : $city_name;
          break;
      }
    }
  }

  // Return the replacements.
  return $replacements;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for providing an example.  They are always helpful

Comment: So the token would be in above example: `[site:city_name]`. Make sure you clear the caches or restart memcached if used.

Comment: Note: `$sanitize` in above example is not defined, so you'll get `Notice: Undefined variable` about that.

Comment: @kenorb good eye, and I see this answer has since been updated :)

Comment: @WebMW Actually, it never was. I fixed it.

Comment: If you'd like to make a token for a certain entity type, change the type to the entity type's machine name, e.g. `node`, `user`, `message`, etc., then the entity will be available in the `$data` array.

Answer (score 6):

**For Drupal 8, example using the node object:**

You can put tokens in your module at mymodule.tokens.inc using hook_token_info() to register them and hook_tokens() for the the replacement data.

If you want to create a custom token for an existing token type, such as for nodes, you'll need to put your token within the subarray within hook_token_info().  Refer to node.tokens.inc in the node module to see what you're building off of.

**mymodule.tokens.inc:**

```
<?php

use Drupal\Core\Render\BubbleableMetadata;
use Drupal\image\Entity\ImageStyle;

/**
 * Implements hook_token_info().
 */
function mymodule_token_info() {
  $info = array();

  $info['tokens']['node']['custom_title'] = [
    'name' => t("Custom Title"),
    'description' => t("a custom node title token"),
  ];
  // Return them.
  return $info;
}

/**
 * Implements hook_tokens().
 */
function mymodule_tokens($type, $tokens, array $data, array $options, BubbleableMetadata $bubbleable_metadata) {

  $replacements = array();
  if ($type == 'node') {
    foreach ($tokens as $name => $original) {
      // Find the desired token by name
      switch ($name) {
        case 'custom_title':
          $node = $data['node'];
          $replacements[$original] = $node->label();
          break;
      }
    }
  }
  // Return the replacements.
  return $replacements;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

**For Drupal 8**

```
// We need to include the needed class for tokens.

use Drupal\Core\Render\BubbleableMetadata;

/**
 * Implements hook_token_info().
 */
function modulename_token_info() {
  $info = array();
  // Add any new tokens.
  $info['tokens']['customtokentype']['customtoken'] = t('Telling drupal that you define custom token');
  // Return them.
  return $info;
}

/**
 * Implements hook_tokens().
 */
function modulename_tokens($type, $tokens, array $data, array $options, BubbleableMetadata $bubbleable_metadata) {
  $replacements = array();
  $simple = $data["customanything"];
  if ($type == 'customtokentype') {
    foreach ($tokens as $name => $original) {
      // Find the desired token by name
      switch ($name) {
        case 'customtoken':
          $new = $simple;
          $replacements[$original] = $new;
          break;
      }
    }
  }   
  // Return the replacements.
  return $replacements;
}
```

Getting the value of tokens in your function requires code similar to the following one.

```
$token = \Drupal::token();
$message_html = "hello my custom token is replaced see it here [customtokentype:customtoken]";

// Token data.
$data = array('customanything' => $tosendtotokens);
$message_html = $token->replace($message_html, $data);
```

Comment: What is `new` and `simple` in this example?

Comment: use Drupal\Core\Render\BubbleableMetadata;
$token = \Drupal::token();                                                                                   function modulename_tokens($type, $tokens, array $data, array $options, BubbleableMetadata $bubbleable_metadata) { ... }

Comment: This should go in modulename.tokens.inc

Answer (score 1):

In `my_module.tokens.inc` place two functions like this:

```
<?php

/**
 * Implements hook_token_info().
 */
function my_module_token_info() {
  $info['tokens']['node']['my_custom_title'] = [
    'name' => t("Custom title"),
    'description' => t("The first 10 characters of the title"),
  ];
  return $info;
}
/**
 * Implements hook_tokens().
 */
function my_module_tokens($type, $tokens, array $data, array $options, \Drupal\Core\Render\BubbleableMetadata $bubbleable_metadata) {
  $replacements = [];
  if ($type == 'node') {
    foreach ($tokens as $name => $original) {
      // Find the desired token by name
      switch ($name) {
        case 'my_custom_title':
          $node = $data['node'];
          $replacements[$original] = substr($node->getTitle(), 0, 10);
          break;
      }
    }
  }
  return $replacements;
}
```

Comment: I created this answer as previous answers by oknate and Karthikeyan had some unecessary complications.