# How do I create custom tokens?

Tags: 7, tokens

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Programmatically create a token](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/4930/programmatically-create-a-token)

How do I create custom tokens?  Also, is it possible to attach a token to a callback function?  For example: If my string is 'this is my [name]', can I somehow make it so that [name] will be replaced with the return value of a function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look this link: [token.inc](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--token.inc/7)
What you need is to create a module that implements hook_tokens and hook_token_info.