# Display all tokens programmatically? Trying to debug token

Tags: 6, tokens

I'm trying to debug creating a token. [How to programmatically create a custom token in a module](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/4930/programmatically-create-a-token) shows me how to create them.

Is there a way to display all available tokens? I'm trying to test if my module actually created that token.

Comment: Do you mean to show the value of the tokens, or to list all the available tokens?

Comment: Good point. I'll specify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a function in the token module called [`token_get_list()`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21token%21token.module/function/token_get_list/6) which is:

> A helper function that retrieves all currently exposed tokens, and merges them recursively.

It invokes [`hook_token_list()`](http://api.drupalhelp.net/api/token/token.api.php/function/hook_token_list/6) for all modules so should give you every single token defined in the site.