# Add site details to be used as tokens throughout site

Tags: tokens

Is there a way to add additional fields to the **config/system/site-information** area such as "business location", "hours of operation", "phone number", etc. I would then like to be able to use that information throughout nodes and blocks as tokens or something like tokens.

That way if a phone number changes or business hours change you can just change it on the config page and it will change throughout the site.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you could achieve this by altering the site information form in a custom module to add a custom submit function which would use the Token API to add desired values in tokens.

I found a good post explaining the token part for 6/7 [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/7008/5475) and a good post for altering the form [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1067855/1197525).

The [module developer's guide](http://drupal.org/developing/modules) is handy too.