# Customizing system response emails outside of the admin panel

Tags: 7, users, emails

Can registration emails be customized through code rather than through the admin panel? I have message content that's reliant on values entered by user. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tokens (provided by the [Token](https://drupal.org/project/token) module) in administrative e-mails.  If you need a token for a value not provided by the Token module, you can [programatically create a token](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/4930/programmatically-create-a-token).