# How to fetch manual flate rate token on replacement pattern

Tags: commerce

How to fetch manual flate rate token on replacement pattern

I added Flate Rate cost manually on orders, but I don't find this token on REPLACEMENT PATTERNS. How to fetch this token for my invoice?

here screenshot that I did
[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You would need to two things to make this happen:

1. [How to programmatically create a custom token](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/4930/how-to-programmatically-create-a-custom-token-in-a-module). And you'll definitely want to read the [API docs](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_tokens/7) on the relevant hook function.
2. How to get at the line item given an order.

Let's assume your token has an $order object inside the $data variable. The next step would be to use [entity metadata wrappers](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/entity-metadata-wrappers) to pull in all the information, including line items.

```
<?php
$order_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_order', $order);
foreach ($order_wrapper->commerce_line_items as $delta => $line_item_wrapper) {
  $line_item = $line_item_wrapper->value();
}
?>
```

Your shipping line item is in there. `dpm($line_item);` to find it and then construct your token output.

Comment: Thanks  a lot joshmiller, but i'm a programmer and need more time to learn. I guess and I wish this token show up when click replacement pattern.

Comment: If you're using rules, you could always "fetch an entity by id" and actually fetch the shipping line item based on the order field. Anything brought into scope for rules would show up as a token.