# Token to show all the comments including comment body for a node

Tags: 7, rules, tokens

I am trying to set up a notification email using rules that will email a forum topic with all the comments including the comment titles and body.

The Message text I have so far is:

> A new forum comment has been posted by
>   [comment:author:profile-main:field-name] with the following details
>
> [comment:node:title]
>
> [comment:node:body]
>
> Comments:
>
> [comment:node:comments]

However, the final token, `[comment:node:comments]`, only shows the comment titles and not the comment body.

Is there a way that I can show the full list of comments including the comment body?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve your issue you can create custom token which contain needed info. Basically you create a module that implements hook_tokens and hook_token_info. For more details see the documentation: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--token.inc/7.

Additional, where you can find examples: 
https://www.drupal.org/node/1308488 and
[How to programmatically create a custom token in a module](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/4930/how-to-programmatically-create-a-custom-token-in-a-module)