# How to use token of Hybridauth?

Tags: authentication-authorization, tokens

I want to display users' profile data from Hybridauth, so I used "Token Filter" to get the token codes (something like [hybridauth:firstName] ), then I put token_replace in 'user-profile.tpl.php':

```
print token_replace('[hybridauth:provider]', array('hybridauth', $hybridauth));
```

But Drupal give me an error message:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: hybridauth in include() (line 41 of /var/www/html/sites/all/themes/mytheme/templates/user-profile.tpl.php).
```

Anyone have any idea about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Jia-Jun Xu In drupal8 To replace global token type

```
print_r(\Drupal::service('token')->replace($data));
```

Here,$data contains the data from where you have to replace the token.

And if you want to replace a custom token.Then first define it in .module file and then replace IT.

```
use Drupal\Core\Render\BubbleableMetadata;
```

[image]

to replace [node:expirydate] from the data

```
print_r(\Drupal::service('token')->replace($data,array('node' => ' ')));
```

Here $data contains data from where token has to be replaced and 'node' is token type.For more information visit on below link
[How to programmatically create a custom token in a module](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/4930/how-to-programmatically-create-a-custom-token-in-a-module)
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Utility%21Token.php/function/Token%3A%3Areplace/8.2.x
Hope it will be useful to you.